# column in data frame with some numbers in double quotes; trying to change to float

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace, dataframe

So I would like to use astype method to change my df column from string to float. but some of the numbers are are in double quotes like so:

```
'"38000.00"'
```

I would like to iterate through the column and replace `"'` or `'"` with: `"`

```
import re
new =  []
for i, x in enumerate(df['TOT_VAL']):
    y = re.sub("\"\'"|"\'\"", '"', x)
    new.append(y)
df['TOT_VAL'] = new
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Try `y = re.sub("\"'|'\"", '"', x)`

Comment: Or, perhaps, `df['TOT_VAL'] = df['TOT_VAL'].str.replace(r"'\"([0-9.]+)\"'", r'"\1"')`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  Thanks for this, but for some reason it didn't work for me. Maybe something on my end.

Comment: Check out the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'apply' will solve this in a much better way. df['TOT_VAL'].apply(lambda x : **float**(x.strip('"'))). I hope it can do a little help.

Comment: i got this error. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '732020.00'

Comment: I forget the type of your data is 'float', anyway, change the int() to float() will better.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `strip()` for this. I don't know what your `pd.DataFrame()` looks like so I just created a simple one here.

```
s = pd.Series(['"39000.00"', '"38000.00"', '"37000.00"'])
data = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['TOT_VAL'])
lst = data['TOT_VAL'].tolist()

lst_strip = [i.strip('"') for i in lst]
to_float = [float(num) for num in lst_strip]

data['TOT_VAL'] = to_float
data
TOT_VAL
0   39000
1   38000
2   37000

data['TOT_VAL'].dtypes
dtype('float64')
```

Comment: can I do this with a vectorized string method?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `'"([\d.]+)"'`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `"\1"`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZ5kB7/1)**